# selenium - how to find xpath

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

can any one help me for finding the correct xpath for the given link [Logout](http://ec2-34-210-163-161.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8094/login/index/logout)

Comment: Show your *incorrect* XPath first

Comment: Any particular language?

Comment: As mentioned above in comment, please provide more info. Html, existing code, eventual exception, and then You might get proper answer. tnx

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to locate all links in your page, and then file the one corresponding to what you're searching for.

Here is the code converted to java

```
public static IWebElement GetLinkContainingText(string textToBeContained) {
    //  Here Driver is my ChromeDriver instance. You can replace a, by whatever tag your href is in.
    ArrayList<WebElement> allTags = Driver.FindElements(By.Xpath("//a"));
    for (WebElement v : allTags) {
        if (v.GetAttribute(href).contains(textToBeContained)) {
            return v;
        }            
    }        
    return null;
}
```

calling the method would result for you in that.

```
WebElement elementYouSeachFor = GetLinkContainingText("http://ec2-34-210-163-161.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8094/login/index/logout");
```

Most likely

```
WebElement elementYouSeachFor = GetLinkContainingText("/logout");
```

would work too since there's probably not many links with logout on your page.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i am using java(selenium)..plz provide for java

Comment: I converted it, please give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Logout']"))
```

Is one way.

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Logout"));
```

Both could be problematic if you have more than **1** **logout** **link** on the page.

More resources on selecting elements: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html